# Setting NSMutableArray after sorting

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nssortdescriptor

I have a NSMutableArray of Marker objects that are shown in a UITableView.  I have a segmentedControl to sort the data.  I know my sorting by Name works when I NSLog my information like so:

```
 // Create sort descriptors
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:descriptor, nil];
    NSArray *sortedArray = [self.MarkersList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    for (Marker *m in self.MarkersList) {
        NSLog(@"-Name: %@", m.Name);
    }
    for (Marker *m in sortedArray) {
        NSLog(@"sorted - Name: %@", m.Name);
    }
```

Then I don't know the best way to reload my data for the UITableView.  I thought I could do the below, but that basically just removes all objects and now I have nothing in self.MarkersList.

```
  if ([segmentControl selectedSegmentIndex] == 0) {
        if (self.MarkersList != nil) {
            [self.MarkersList removeAllObjects];

            [self.MarkersList arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:sortedArray];
            [self.MarkersTableView reloadData];
            NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

            for (Marker *m in self.MarkersList) {
                NSLog(@"Name: %@", m.Name);
            }   
        }        
    }
```

I'm definitely missing something obvious at this point.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
[self.MarkersList arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:sortedArray];
```

With:

```
[self.MarkersList addObjectsFromArray:sortedArray];
```

Spot the mistake and rejoice!

Comment: right, because arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray return a NEW array, this method do not add objects to the current array

Comment: Indeed. The following would also have worked (but is not my recommended approach) self.MarketsList = [NSArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:sortedArray];

Comment: Thanks guys!  Knew it'd be something like that.